# Connection from VS Code to Kubernetes failing

Tags: kubernetes, visual-studio-code, azure-aks

I am receiving an error message when trying to access details from VS Code of my Azure Kubernetes Cluster. This problem prevents me from attaching a debugger to the pod.

I receive the following error message:

```
Error loading document: Error: cannot open k8smsx://loadkubernetescore/pod-kube-system%20%20%20coredns-748cdb7bf4-q9f9x.yaml?ns%3Dall%26value%3Dpod%2Fkube-system%20%20%20coredns-748cdb7bf4-q9f9x%26_%3D1611398456559. Detail: Unable to read file 'k8smsx://loadkubernetescore/pod-kube-system   coredns-748cdb7bf4-q9f9x.yaml?ns=all&value=pod/kube-system   coredns-748cdb7bf4-q9f9x&_=1611398456559' (Get command failed: error: there is no need to specify a resource type as a separate argument when passing arguments in resource/name form (e.g. 'kubectl get resource/<resource_name>' instead of 'kubectl get resource resource/<resource_name>'
)
```

**My Setup**

- I have VS Code installed, with "Kubernetes", "Bridge to Kubernetes" and "Azure Kubernetes Service" installed
- I have connected my Cluster through az login and can already access  different information (e.g. my nodes, etc.)
- When trying to access the workloads / pods on my cluster, I receive the above error message - and in the Kubernetes View in VS Code I get an error for the details of the pod.
  [Error in Kubernetes-View in VS Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oIsan.png)

**What I tried**

- I tried to reinstall the AKS Cluster and completely logging in freshly to it
- I tried to reinstall all extensions mentioned above in VS Code
- Browsing the internet, I do not find any comparable error message
- The strange thing is that it used to work two weeks ago - and I did not change or update anything (as far as I remember)

Any ideas / hints that I can try further?

Thank you

Comment: Hi Eduard, welcome to SO. I would _guess_ that Node view is just for human consumption, and that the tree item you actually want to click on is underneath Namespaces / kube-system / coredns-748cdb7bf4-q9f9x. Give that a try, and consider reporting your bad experience [to their issue tracker](https://github.com/Azure/vscode-kubernetes-tools/issues) since it looks like release 1.2.2 just came out 2 days ago and might not have been tested well

Comment: Hi @mdaniel, thanks for the warm welcome and the quick answer. Very much appreciated The hint helped me to find another way to attach the debugger - through Workloads / Deployments. Topic is solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @mdaniel wrote: the  Node view is just for human consumption, and that the tree item you actually want to click on is underneath Namespaces `/ kube-system / coredns-748cdb7bf4-q9f9x`. Give that a try, and consider reporting your bad experience  [to their issue tracker](https://github.com/Azure/vscode-kubernetes-tools/issues)  since it looks like release 1.2.2 just came out 2 days ago and might not have been tested well.

final solution is to attach debugger in the other way - through Workloads / Deployments.